# Twitteroauth with localhost

Tags: twitter, localhost, wamp, twitter-oauth

I currently have a website up and running that uses the Twitteroauth classes (abraham's) and the Twitter API. It is all working as it should, however, I want to also run the project on my localhost for debugging/coding purposes so that I am not in danger of messing up my live version.

I am wondering if it is possible to run Twitterouth on localhost. I know that there are ways to manipulate the callback URL of the application on Twitter's site, however I do not want to do that as my live version needs the callback URL.

I hope this makes sense and I hope there is a solution out there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Twitteroauth in localhost. You should make a copy of your project files from your website and copy it to your localhost. 
You might see a file "config.php" where you'll define the callback url.

```
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://localhost/path_to_callback.php file');
```

It will redirect you to your callback.php file and it works in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

For running Abramham William's twitteraouth locally , you can create another test application on twitter so that it don't disturb the live version . Then instead of using localhost/ in your address bar , you should use the IP address of your localhost , this mistake by me consumed a lot of time . 
Example :
**127.0.0.1**/twittertest/index.php and not localhost/twittertest/index.php in your address bar .

You'll need to give the same oauth callback in your twitter application .